# How to make a similar article/content appear on a specified scroll point?

Tags: jquery, scroll, appearance

Nowadays on a lot of sites when I scroll down and reach a specified point I see these recommendation boxes where a box of content suddenly appears and It shows some kind of similar articles or recommendations.

I would be interested in the process of making this feature. I am not interested in recommendation systems or anything like that I am just interested in the technique that shows the box of content at a specified scroll point.

Is there a script out there or do I have to figure it out on my own and write the script? Is it some kind of Jquery maybe?

I would appreciate any word on this problem.

A good reference for what I am looking for is The Economist's site where You click on an article, scroll down and a similar article appears in the right bottom corner.

Here is a reference link on a random article where the function perfectly works:
http://www.economist.com/news/leaders/21571136-politicians-both-right-and-left-could-learn-nordic-countries-next-supermodel

Comment: I don't see anything in the bottom right corner of that Economist page.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Party yes! So Thank You for taking the time it really put me closer to the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to use scrollTop. http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/ Basically you look for the scroll position and do something when it gets to a certain point.

Here is a fiddle: crude demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/YtGrf/

```
$('#test').scroll(function(){
    var loc = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(loc > 150) {
        alert('fire');
    }
});
```

Comment: This snippet works great I just thought there is a plugin somewhere because a lot of sites use this way to promote their similar articles.

So maybe I need to use PHP+this snippet to generate the similar article content box, then just hide it with css and when the user scroll to a point the jquery manipulates the css code so it the content be seen. 

Do You think thats the way they do it?

Comment: There might be a plugin, but I mean, that's pretty much it. Just make a div positioned where you want it on the page and hidden. When the user scrolls to where you want it to show, change the alert to make it display either via css, javascript, or any other magic you want. It's pretty simple. The harder part is getting a related article via PHP and populating the div.